# can't boot dd'ed and VMDK'ed Linux image in Virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vmdk

i've been trying to recover a lnx install (Debian 4.0) from bro's old notebook.

i've dd'd the drive over ssh to my puter, but after i made an vmdk image for use in virtualbox, i got this error during booting up:

mount - mounting /dev/sda1 on /mnt-system failed: No such device or address.
could not mount OS on /dev/sda1. starting debugging shell.

any clues on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How did you go about turning the `dd` copy into a vmdk image?

Comment: VBoxManage convertfromraw /root/sda sda.vmdk --format VMDK